# cannot read serial data on cubieboard with stock android on the board

Tags: java, android, linux, serial-port, uart

I am developing a project where I need to read data from TX of UART from cubie board, but i cannot read any data from cubie board. The error was I cannot read/write the serial data on cubie board.
I have tried chmod on terminal of android, but I don't have permission to change the chmod of the ttyS0.
Is there any way to get serial data from some serial transmitting device in android on cubie board.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Regards,
YOGX

Comment: *"on cubieboard"*, *"from cubie board"*, *"from cubie board"*, *"on cubie board"* and *"on cubie board"*.  Okay, which is it?  Your arbitrary use of prepositions is confusing.  What is the source? What is the destination.  How are you "writing"?  How are you "reading"?

Comment: to rephrase the question, the goal is to read data from UART port in Android app and send the info read over internet. But i am not able to read any data.:(

Answer (score 0):

Use chmod after fed file config:

chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS0